# implicit wait is waiting is not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i have set an implicit wait for my driver object as in the code bellow:

```
public void setImplicitWait(
                                 int waitTime_InSeconds ) {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( waitTime_InSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
    }
```

now the problem is that it doesn't matter when the element will be found or displayed the setImplicitWait will not finish executing untill the waitTime_InSeconds variable is finished. any ideas please ?

Comment: This is the documented behaviour of implicit waits. Have you considered using explicit waits instead (or no wait at all, where appropriate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you use global variable for web-driver?
You can try to use a parameter like this:

```
public void setImplicitWait(WebDriver myWebdriver, int waitTime_InSeconds) {

    myWebdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(waitTime_InSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Hi Minh,I have created a local variable within the method but i get a nullpointer exception error i did the following:  WebDriver myWebdriver = null;

        try {
            setImplicitWait( myWebdriver, timeout );
            driver.findElement( By.xpath( xpathElement ) ).isDisplayed();

        } catch( NoSuchElementException e ) {
            nullifyImplicitWait();
            found = false;
        }

Comment: Hi Ali, before use webdriver, you have to assign value for webdriver, example: WebDriver myWebdriver = new FireFoxDriver(); <= I don't remember it exactly. You can add my skype: "minhnph@hotmail.com" or "live:minhnph" and then I can easily support you :)

Comment: Thank you Minh, I have added you to my skype list looking forward to share some further information.